# Execute Start-Process Powershell Script on a Remote Computer

Tags: powershell, updates, remote-access, invoke-command, start-process

I open PowerShell as admin and use the following line of code to run an offline file for windows updates. It works fine

```
Start-Process 'wusa.exe' -ArgumentList 'C:\Temp\windows10.0-kb5032189-x64_0a3b690ba3fa6cd69a2b0f989f273cfeadba745f.msu' -verb runas
```

But now I am trying to somehow use this same code to run the file on remote computers. The windows update file has the same name and the exact location on the remote PCs

I came up with this code below which first gets admin credentials and passes it to the the invoke-command. Then the invoke-command runs the Start-Process code.

```
$Username = 'username123'
$Password = '84fWfghnsf&5Fh'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$pass
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 8HPF31J7V6.domain.local -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {Start-Process 'wusa.exe' -ArgumentList 'C:\Temp\windows10.0-kb5032189-x64_0a3b690ba3fa6cd69a2b0f989f273cfeadba745f.msu' -verb runas}
```

Problem is, when I do this, nothing happens on the remote PC

I also don't get any errors when running

[image]

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong, or any other solutions besides this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Add `-Wait` to your remote [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) call to ensure that `wusa.exe` *runs to completion*** before returning from the remote [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) call.

  - Otherwise, with an *ad-hoc* remoting session implicitly created via use of the `-ComputerName` parameter, the `Start-Process`-launched process is *automatically terminated* when the `Invoke-Command` call returns.
- Code executed via PowerShell's [remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote) runs *invisibly* on the target machines, so the **use of `-Verb RunAs` is pointless**:

  - If the remote process already *is* elevated, it has *no effect*.   Note that remote processes are *automatically elevated* if the user identity running the remote command is an administrator on the target machine.
  - If it isn't (this would only happen if you explicitly gave non-administrative users permission to use PowerShell remoting), the call *invariably fails*, because no UAC dialog can be presented.

**Caveat**:

- While the information below in this answer is correct in principle, [js2010](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6654942/js2010) notes that in order  to successfully run `wusa.exe` remotely, i.e. in order to install *Windows Updates*, running in an implicitly elevated remote session alone may *not* be sufficient.
- [This ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/559287/what-does-wusa-exe-return-code-5-mean) provides background information, and [third-party module `PSWindowsUpdate`](https://github.com/mgajda83/PSWindowsUpdate) may provide a solution, *if used with its scheduling features*.

---

Therefore, with ***synchronous* execution**:

```bash
# ... credential construction code ($Cred) omitted
# Note: If the *current user* is allowed to make remoting calls,
#       you may not need to construct credentials and don't need the 
#       -Credential parameter below.

# Note the use of -Wait, removal of -Verb RunAs
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 8HPF31J7V6.domain.local -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {
  Start-Process -Wait wusa.exe -ArgumentList 'C:\Temp\windows10.0-kb5032189-x64_0a3b690ba3fa6cd69a2b0f989f273cfeadba745f.msu'
}
```

Read on for an asynchronous alternative.
Note that the `(Start-Process -PassThru …).ExitCode` technique shown below, for **reporting the remote process' exit code**, can equally be used with the synchronous approach above.

---

***Asynchronous* execution**:

**If you don't want the `Invoke-Command` call to wait for the remotely launched process (`wusa.exe`) to terminate**, you have two options:

- In the simplest case, add the **`-AsJob` switch** to the call above, which makes `Invoke-Command` return a [job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_jobs) object that can be queried for output and completion later, on demand, with [`Receive-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/receive-job) and [`Wait-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/wait-job), as shown below.
- **Create a remote session *explicitly***, via [`New-PSSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-pssession), and pass it to `Invoke-Command`'s `-Session` parameter. Such a session stays open until it is either explicitly removed with [`Remove-PSSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/remove-pssession) or times out due to inactivity.

  - However, to make the call asynchronous, you must then *not* use `-Wait` with `Start-Process`, and track the lifetime of the process *in the remote session*, by adding `-PassThru` to output a process-information object that you must capture in a variable, and consult again in a *later* `Invoke-Command` call with the same `-Session` argument.

**Asynchronous variant with `-AsJob`**, which **additionally demonstrates how to report the remote process' *exit code***:

```bash
# ... credential construction code omitted

# Note the use of -AsJob and the use of -PassThru with Start-Process
# so as to be able to report the process' exit code.
$remoteJob = 
  Invoke-Command -AsJob -ComputerName 8HPF31J7V6.domain.local -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {
    (
      Start-Process -Wait -PassThru wusa.exe -ArgumentList 'C:\Temp\windows10.0-kb5032189-x64_0a3b690ba3fa6cd69a2b0f989f273cfeadba745f.msu'
    ).ExitCode
  }

# ... perform foreground activity here.

# Now wait for the remote job to complete - which happens when 
# wusa.exe terminates - and report its exit code.
$exitCode = 
  $remoteJob | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

Comment: Thank you! I am new to PowerShell, so the explanations of everything will help. I think the asynchronous version will work best.

I would still initiate username and password variables in the beginning correct?

Comment: Glad to hear it, @TevinMosley. Yes, you still need the credential construction code - I just omitted it for brevity, to focus on the gist of the solution.

Comment: There may be a rights problem running windows updates remotely.  Usually with a powershell module that runs windows update, it does it through task scheduler as a workaround.

Comment: @mklement0 Ok, so I got the first synchronous execution going and I can see the Windows Update Standalone Installer in the Task Manager. But it has been sitting there for over an hour. 

Do you think the credentials are failing and, since there is no UAC, it is invisibly waiting for input?

Comment: @TevinMosley, assuming the user whose credentials you're using is an administrator on the remote machine, the command should invariably run with elevation, so there should be no attempt to elevate (and if there were, I'd expect it to fail right away, but I'm not certain). However, js2010's comment suggests that calling `wusa.exe` directly from an elevated remoting session may still not be enough and may require a workaround via a scheduled task; unfortunately, I can't be of further help, but I suggest you ask them for details.

Comment: @js2010, can you point us to answers and/or further information about this?

Comment: How about this one?  I was getting exit code 5 myself trying to test it.  https://serverfault.com/questions/559287/what-does-wusa-exe-return-code-5-mean

Comment: The pswindowsupdate module is popular:  https://github.com/mgajda83/PSWindowsUpdate.  To run an update remotely, you have to schedule it.

Comment: Thanks, @js2010: I've added your pointers to the answer.

Comment: @js2010 Thanks! I'm looking at these links, for alternate methods, you posted now. Will let you know how they work